# matching query does not exist in django

Tags: django, matching

the url:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', views.reports, name='reports'),
    url(r'^(?P<did>\d+)/pdf/$', views.pdf),
    url(r'^(?P<dated>\d+)/$',views.dated)
)
```

the view:

```
def dated(request,dated):
    l=str(dated)
    s=len(l)
    if s==6:
        a1=''
        a2=l[:2]
        a3=l[2:6]
        p=freshh.objects.filter(expirydate__year=a3,expirydate__month=a2)
        q=renewall.objects.filter(expirydate__year=a3,expirydate__month=a2)
        r=enhancementt.objects.filter(expirydate__year=a3,expirydate__month=a2)
    elif s==8:
        a1=l[4:8]
        a2=l[2:4]
        a3=l[:2]
        a=a1+'-'+a2+'-'+a3
        p=freshh.objects.filter(expirydate__range=[a,a])
        q=renewall.objects.filter(expirydate__range=[a,a])
        q=enhancementt.objects.filter(expirydate__range=[a,a])
    elif s==16:
        a1=l[:2]
        a2=l[2:4]
        a3=l[4:8]
        a4=l[8:10]
        a5=l[10:12]
        a6=l[12:16]
        p=freshh.objects.filter(expirydate__range=[a3+'-'+a2+'-'+a1,a6+'-'+a5+'-'+a4])
        q=renewall.objects.filter(expirydate__range=[a3+'-'+a2+'-'+a1,a6+'-'+a5+'-'+a4])
        r=enhancementt.objects.filter(expirydate__range=[a3+'-'+a2+'-'+a1,a6+'-'+a5+'-'+a4])
    else:
        p=None
        q=None
        r=None
    template = loader.get_template('templates/files.html')
    context = RequestContext(request,{'p':p,'q':q,'r':r,})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

I need to query data in different ways based on date, the format may be 032014; 02032014; 01022014,20022014. when I tried by the url 'localhost/files/032014/', it shows

```
DoesNotExist at /files/032014/
files matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    localhost/files/032014/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
files matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in get, line 307
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
```

but yesterday, the same query yielded result

Comment: Is there a traceback with the error message?

Comment: You're going to need to show the traceback, as well as the models involved for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry for being late, unfortunately(!) my query is running well today, though I did make no change today, i.e., I am now unable to figure out what went wrong yesterday. Now I fear a situation when I will be stuck up again in future in the problem described above.